# Not syncing files on Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, file-upload, sync, limitations

If I only use the documents in a Sharepoint library when I'm online, is there any reason to sync the documents? And if I don't sync the documents, can I avoid the 20,000 file limit? I'm thinking that syncing is unnecessary for me, and hoping that I can upload more documents this way, I just want to make sure I don't have a fundamental misunderstanding of how this works.

Update - thank you for the responses. It seemed like a simple question but I had a hard time finding a simple answer. Is there any reason why I would not want to store all of my business documents and not sync them? Should I have any concerns about security or losing data?

Thanks again, I really appreciate the help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, if you only use documents online then there is no need to sync the library. And if you don't sync, then you can avoid the 20,000 item (files + folders) sync limit. In fact, you can have many hundreds of thousands of files + folders in your OneDrive for Business if you don't need to sync.

The sync limit is confirmed [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-software-boundaries-and-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498).

Note that if you do need to sync, you can always create new document libraries in your OneDrive for Business and sync each individual library as a means to keep below the sync limit.

To create a new library sign in to https://portal.office.com/ click OneDrive then click the "cog" icon top right. Now choose "add an app" then choose the document library.

Clarification: the sync limit is only 5,000 items for SharePoint Online team site libraries. It is 20,000 for OneDrive for Business

Answer (score 1):

Cody, as you said that you use documents in the library when you are online. So, you don't need to `sync` the documents. As you are aware the `sync` feature makes a local copy of the document on the user's machine(file system), which you don't need. So, you are good to go.

Since, you are not `syncing` the documents then the limit of 20,000 documents is not even in question for you. The limit will only apply for those who are using the `sync` feature.